# Frame ripple tap effect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin forms, I using a frame that has TapGestureRecognizer, but when the frame is clicked there is no tap effect, how can i give a ripple tap effect to the frame like a button has?

Here a example, this look like a frame with a tap event, right?

Example:
https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-d9abfdafef.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with frames, its not there intended purpose.

What about using a normal button ? Then setting Your Theme to Material in your native Android project. You can learn how to do it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/material-theme)

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
</application>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can get a sample on how to do it in forms [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/card-view) but you will not get that ripple effect your looking for

Comment: Here is a example, this look like a frame:
https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-d9abfdafef.gif

Comment: @Phill That's a native android card https://material.io/design/components/cards.html

Comment: Here is a sample on how to do it in forms , but you will not have that ripple effect your looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/card-view